# Creating an API resource from a table/model with no primary key

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am working on a database that I cannot mutate, and in the shortest explanation possible, it has a pivot table that can be accessed by combining two other table IDs, and then from there I can locate a 4th table's record.

The front end will have access to the first two IDs, meaning that I can locate the pivot ID, and then pull the last table's content with something like

```
select * from needed_table where pivot_table_id = (
    select id from pivot_table where user_id = 123 and other_table_id = 890
);
```

I would like to be able to set a single route, `Route::apiResource('user/{userId}/other/{otherTableId}/needed', NeededController::class);`, but I feel like resources require an ID to populate the store, destroy, update functions, is that right?

Is there a way to modify the resource's sql such that it isn't looking for a primary key on those functions, but instead the above SQL? I am assuming not, as I have searched all day and haven't found anything.

Thanks in advance, even if no.

Comment: `Route::apiResource('user/{userId:columnName}/other/{otherTableId}/needed',` here `columnName` you can put to not search by primary key

Comment: Oh that's right, I had forgotten about that syntax. I wonder if I can make that work. I'll go kick it around. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so this would work easily if we weren't passing through a pivot table. I'm going to try modifying the Resource's constructor to define the resource based on these, but it doesn't feel like "the Laravel way" yet. I'm going to leave this open for the time being, but I'm still trying to fiddle with it.

Comment: @KamleshPaul, after some work, i actually WAS able to get this to work. Please submit as an answer so I can check mark you. :)

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this, rather than tablenames, I used
`Route::apiResource('resource-root/{PivotClassName:resourceColumnNameInPivot}/other-resource/{otherResourceColumnName}/column-i-want', IWantController::class);`, real world example: `Route::apiResource('users/{LocationToUserLocationPivot:userId}/locations/{locationId}/client', ClientController::class);` where the pivot table delivers the id of a client when provided a user and location.